# Can a message that was registered using 'RegisterWindowMessage' be unregistered?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winapi, wndproc

Strangely there is no (at least documented) `UnregisterWindowMessage` function to ensure that no more notifications of that message will be sent and handled between both applications.

Can  a message that was registered using **[RegisterWindowMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** be unregistered or not?

Comment: [They can't](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150319-00/?p=44433).

Comment: They can, in a way. Not with very fine-grained control, or without collateral damage. Just call [`ExitWindowsEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376868.aspx)`(EWX_LOGOFF, 0)`.

Comment: Seriously, though, who ever would vote to close this question as *"primarily opinion-based"*? How is *"does xyz exist?"* subject to opinion?

Comment: @IInspectable and theB Thanks for the info, and no matter about the closure vote or the downvote, Intenet trolls will exists in this world for some reason, or people who doesn't knows an answer so they will downvote because everything on which they don't know the answer it will be considered "bad" (so, a "bad" question), or maybe are nice people who just doesn't apply a good criterion reading others.

Comment: @IInspectable - Indeed. `InitiateShutdown(NULL, L"Unregister a message.", 0, SHUTDOWN_RESTART)` would work as well. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no [UnregisterWindowMessage](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150319-00/?p=44433) and no alternatives like GlobaladdAtom/GlobalDeleteAtom available. To ensure that no more notifications are handled you could register and use a 'HANDLE NOTIFICATIONS OFF/ON' type of message.